# Finding supporting planes and bounds for function

Tags: optimization, self-learning

I am working with this function:
$$f(x)=x_1^2+2x_2^2+3x_3^2$$
With the $\min f(x)$ in $-10<=x_i<=10, i=1,2,3$.

I was given two points: $p_1=(1,1,1)$ and $p_2=(-1,2,1)$.

Using these points I have to find the supporting planes of $f$ for $p_1$ and $p_2$ and computing the upper and lower bounds for it.

I know that using this expression $f(p_1)+\nabla f(p_1)(x-p_1)$ I got a supporting plane but I have to find the upper and lower bounds for $\min f(x)$.
This would mean formulating a master problem but I am confused on how to compute the supporting planes and formulate the problem to solve it.

Please could you give some help?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal vector of the supporting plane in the point $p=(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ is
$$\nabla f(p) = \{2p_1, 4p_2, 6p_3\}.$$
Equation of the supporting plane for the point $p_1 = (1,1,1)$ is
$$f(p_1) + \nabla f(p_1)\cdot(x-p_1) = 0,$$
$$1^2 + 2\cdot1^2 + 3\cdot 1^2 + \{2,4,6\}\cdot\{x_1-1,x_2-1,x_3-1\}=0,$$
or
$$f_1(x) = 2x_1+4x_2+6x_3-6=0.$$

Equation of the supporting plane for the point $p_2 = (-1,2,1)$ is
$$f(p_2) + \nabla f(p_2)\cdot(x-p_2) = 0,$$
$$(-1)^2 + 2\cdot2^2 + 3\cdot 1^2 + \{-2,8,6\}\cdot\{x_1+1,x_2-2,x_3-1\}=0,$$
or
$$f_2(x) = -2x_1+8x_2+6x_3-12=0.$$

The least value of function achieves in the stationary points or in the edges of the area.

The stationary points of $f(x)$ can be found from the equation $\nabla f(p_m) = 0,$ then
$$p_m = \{0,0,0\},\quad f(p_m) = 0.$$

The edges of the area belongs to the planes $x_1 = \pm 10,\quad x_2=\pm10, x_3=\pm10.$

\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & f(x) & \in\\
-10 & [-10,10] & [-10,10] & 2x_2^2+3x_3^2+100 & [100,600]\\
10 & [-10,10] & [-10,10] & 2x_2^2+3x_3^2+100 & [100,600]\\
[-10,10] & -10 & [-10,10] & x_1^2+3x_3^2+200 & [200,600]\\
[-10,10] & 10 & [-10,10] & x_1^2+3x_3^2+200 & [200,600]\\
[-10,10] & [-10,10] & -10 & x_1^2+2x_2^2+300 & [300,600]\\
[-10,10] & [-10,10] & 10 & x_1^2+2x_2^2+300 & [300,600]\\
\end{vmatrix}

The least value $\color{brown}{f(p_m)=0}$ achives in the stationary point (minimum) $\color{brown}{p_m=\{0,0,0\}}.$

Function $f(x)$ is convex, so upper bound $\color{brown}{\sup(\min f(x))=100}.$

Let us find the lower bounds for $\min f(x).$

The least value of linear function in the rectangle area achives in the vertex of the area.

\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & f_1(x) & f_2(x)\\
-10 & -10 & -10 & -126   & -132\\
-10 & -10 &  10 &   -6   &  -12\\
-10 &  10 & -10 &  -46   &   28\\
-10 &  10 &  10 &   74   &  148\\
 10 & -10 & -10 &  -86   & -172\\
 10 & -10 &  10 &   34   &  -52\\
 10 &  10 & -10 &   -6   &  -12\\
 10 &  10 &  10 &  114   &  108\\
\end{vmatrix}

Support plane $f_1(x)$ leads to lower bound $\inf(\min f(x)) = \min f_1(x) = -126,$

Support plane $f_2(x)$ leads to lower bound $\inf(\min f(x)) = \min f_1(x) = -172.$

The best estimation is $\color{brown}{\inf(\min f(x)) = -126}.$